# The history of the Parshiot division

Tags: provenance, parsha-torah-portion

The Gemarah does not seem to make much mention of the 54 Torah Parshiot in the annual Torah reading. I don't know, offhand, what Ramba"m mentions about them either.

- Who organized both the annual and tri-annual readings, in general,
  and when were they organized? Why were there differences (annual vs.
  tri-annual)?
- How were the Parshiot decided? (Where each Parsha begins, the Parsha "names", Breishit, Noach, etc. (I know the name is taken from a word near the start of the parsha; I'm curious who decided on where each Parsha begins?)
- Who decided which Parshiot should be doubled?

Comment: http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A2 might be useful to you....haven't read it through yet, might post an answer if I find something that directly deals with your problem

Comment: @Shokhet - Offhand, this looks like a start. My Hebrew is pretty good to understand it. But, an English source would be a huge help, since I can more easily copy / paste for my lecture.

Comment: ( *There's a little link on the side of the page that says "דף זה בשפות אחרות" ....clicking on "English" brought me [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weekly_Torah_portion)* )

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/82085/759

Comment: @DanF I have a bad habit of duplicating your questions, don’t I?

Comment: @DonielF Don't worry. It's nowhere as bad as the habit I have of duplicating my own questions!