# Why are those parshios in particular combined?

Tags: minhag, calendar, torah-reading, parsha-torah-portion

The Tur (OC 428), as explained by the Tiferes Yisrael (Shevili d'Rakia 15), lists four dates that must fall out at certain points in the leining cycle:

- Pesach must fall out after Tzav in a non-leap year or after Metzora or Acharei  in a leap year
- Shavuos must fall out after Bamidbar
- Tishah B'av must fall out after Devarim
- Rosh Hashanah must fall out after Netzavim

In order to account for these, Shvili d'Rakia continues, depending on the year and place, the following parshios might be combined or split:

- Vayakhel-Pekudei
- Tazria-Metzora
- Acharei-Kedoshim
- Behar-Bechukosai
- Chukas-Balak
- Mattos-Maasei
- Netzavim-Vayeilech

None of these make sense. Why can't we pick other parshios to combine? For instance, this week is Tazria-Metzora. Why don't we combine Shemini and Tazria instead, in a non-leap year? Why not combine Emor and Behar instead of Behar and Bechukosai? Why not Vayeilech and Haazinu instead of Netzavim and Vayeilech? There are any number of combinations that could be made for each of these gaps; why do we pick these in particular?

(If you want to point to length, we combine Mattos-Maasei and Vayakhel-Pekudei. If you want to point to similar content, we combine Chukas-Balak while we don't combine  Vayeilech-Haazinu, or Lech Lecha-Vayeira, or Vayeishev-Miketz, or Va'eira-Bo, or Bo-Beshalach, or Yisro-Mishpatim, or Terumah-Tetzaveh.)

Comment: Vayelekh is just the end of Netzavim. We split Netzavim in some years. It wouldn't make any sense to split Netzavim just to combine the second half with Haazinu

Comment: There are also other customs like splitting Chukkat in half and reading half with Korach and half with Balak. There were other customs to ensure Tzav was Shabbat haGadol even in a leap year so theyd split mishpatim Terumah Tetzaveh and Tisa into two each

Comment: See also the Tanya Rabbati which records a variant Mesora of the Parasha names and count. See also the footnote here which brings a third version from Machzor Romi: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bhg6joc6cll175j/Tanya%20Rabbasi-%20Three%20Versions%20of%20Parasha%20Names.pdf?dl=0

Comment: @DoubleAA Where do you get that first comment from? As for the second, if you source that it could be the makings of an answer.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15600/when-israel-and-the-diaspora-are-out-of-sync-on-parshiyot-why-dont-we-take-the

Comment: Davka Tazria-Metzora make sense! 2 short parshiot that both discuss the same laws, i.e. Tzora'at.

Comment: @DannySchoemann Same question, but I don't find the answer satisfactory. Have you heard anyone lein Terumah-Tetzaveh? Or go further back - Lech Lecha-Vayeira makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: I see that this question is a dupe. B"N, when I have time, I'll post an additional answer in the other question. Meanwhile, have a look at http://www.hakirah.org/vol%202%20epstein.pdf. It is a long article, but, the analysis is quite good, and, I think will provide you a bit better understanding than what was posted in the linked question. I've kept this article in my "Torah file" for years and occasionally view it for reference and when I give lectures on the laining system and the Jewish calendar. It's a great reference.

Comment: @DonielF I don't see how anything I said is the making of an answer

Comment: @Chaim Those are different names, but I don't see how that's relevant at all here.

Comment: @DoubleAA it's relevant because according to that Mesora, Nitzavim and Vayelekh are never "combined" - they are rather always one unit which, at times, needs to be split.

Comment: @Chaim you may want to read the article I linked to in my last comment to DonielF. It explains the story behind Netzavim / Vayelech.